# How to add remoteproc node into device tree of Zynq-7000 Based RedPitaya board

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, fpga, xilinx, zynq

I am trying to run the RedPitaya in AMP mode.

I didn't find much information on the remoteproc driver and what kind of entries it need in the device tree source. I found [this](https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/blob/master/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/remoteproc/zynq_remoteproc.txt) document and added it to the device tree but hadn't so much luck with making the examples work. Also I found different variations in the device tree node for remoteproc from different sources which is pretty confusing.

Can someone point me in the direction where I can read more about the AMP feature of the Arm-Cortex-A9 and can some explain some of the entries in the dts node of remoteproc.

Answer (score 1):

It's me the OP. I managed to run some AMP examples in PetaLinux on ZedBoard. The process is described in [Libmetal and OpenAMP User Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_3/ug1186-zynq-openamp-gsg.pdf). The most important part of the document is titled "Setting up PetaLinux with OpenAMP" on page 32 in linked version above.

There are two steps, remoteproc support in Kernel and specifying space for remote application in kernel configuration. The second step is adding the device tree nodes for remoteproc to device tree source.

I made a video tutorial on how to do it which explains it better I think. Here is the link: [Tutorial 07 Asymmetric Multi-Processing on ZedBoard (OpenAMP, remoteproc, petalinux)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7nQ84Bc08E)

I am still working on how to compile my own application to be run in AMP mode as there are memory related issues which I hadn't completely grasped yet. I will update the answer as I figure them out. Peace out.
Waqar

Answer (score 0):

What different sources? Are you talking about kernel sources? Device tree node entry would be dependent on the kernel version and the actual driver thereof, changing if there is a change in the driver or kernel remoteproc subsystem.

ZynqQ-7000 is a dual core Cortex A9. Based on cursory reading of the documentation, the remoteproc driver in question assumes one core running Linux and the other core to help with other real time tasks. mmio-sram is described [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/sram/sram.txt). Not sure what specific ZynqQ hardware design, the device tree binding documentation talks of.

To understand vrings, you need an understanding of virtio and rpmsg used in [open-amp](https://github.com/OpenAMP/open-amp) and Linux. A vring can be thought of as a ring buffer, with one buffer being used to send from Master to Slave and another from slave to master. A interrupt is associated with each vring which is raised when either Master or Slave places something in the vring and then wants to inform the other end.

In case of Linux based systems, Linux is always the master. For Zynq since we are using the two A9's, this will be an inter processor interrupt. For SoC's like NXP's iMX7 or Vybrid, the interrupts are raised with a separate peripheral module like the Messaging Unit for iMX7.

Comment: I meant here the device tree node is a bit different than that in the device tree binding http://henryomd.blogspot.com/2015/02/zynq-amp-linux-on-cpu0-and-bare-metal.html

Comment: I did not see what version of kernel he is using. Probably old since at least in 4.14 or later no dma_declare_coherent_memory call exists in zynq_remoteproc driver..If the driver has changed or remoteproc subsystem has changed and does not look for certain properties, the device tree binding will also accordingly changed. A device tree binding is not constant across all kernel versions. Also he does a lot of custom modifications..

Comment: Yeah you are right. I did manage to run an example application and would write a detailed answer here once I have all the answered. I just added the dts node described in the remoteproc binding for zynq-7000 and compiled petalinux with AMP support and applications according to the OpenAMP Framework for Zynq Devices: Getting Started Guide (UG1186) and now I can execute the application. I still hadn't managed to compile my own application but will look at the remote applications the petalinux built and will hopefully figure out what I have to change in Xilinx SDK to make them work.